# How to add conditional content in card messages Google Chat API?

Tags: google-hangouts

I am using webhook integration for my contact form with the help of google chat API.
I am having an optional field for comments in my form. I want to display the comment field value in the [card message](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#full_example_pizza_bot) conditionally i.e. if the comments field is empty this shouldn't be shown in the card message and vice-versa.

What is the possible way to implement the above scenario?

Comment: What client are you using for the integration? How are you calling Google Chat API?

Comment: Hi @Martí, here is my implementation https://gist.github.com/suraj235/7857c3d0241b4381af08978d6682289b

Comment: So you are basically calling the REST API raw using PHP. What you need to do is modify the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to contain a JSON with the card values that you'd like. You can do so dynamically adding all the logic that you want. How fluent are you with PHP?